# Set directory permissions so process inside can’t "access outside"

Tags: linux, permissions

How may I setup permissions for a directory, so that a C program compiled and launched inside that directory can’t access files and directories outside that dir (ex. via `fopen`).

Comment: The correct way to do this is to use a [chroot jail](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105/chroot-jail-what-is-it-and-how-do-i-use-it). More information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this by setting permissions on a directory.

Your best option to achieve this is using [`chroot`](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=chroot).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to create a new user (e.g. Cscript) and create a directory and chown it to that user.

But if any of your directories have the read flag set in the 'others' position (E.g. 777, 755) then it will still be able to access that directory. If you cannot reasonably change the permissions of all your other folders to not include this flag, you will probably want to run it in some sort of sandbox or virtual machine.